# 503 error after visual studio aws toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've searched a lot to solve my problem and i lack the background about AWS.
I published my ASP.NET Core Web Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk i followed the tutorials and the publish succeeded.

[image]

Unfortunately i get the error 503 every time i launch the environment
[image]

I tried to read the logs from the logs tab
[image]

and i didn't find the problem source, I'll provide the first part of the generated logs in this post hoping for some help, if i should provide the whole content let me know.
[image]

I'm desperately waiting for answers

Comment: Your application cannot connect to your database.  Where is your database supposed to be?

Comment: @stdunbar it looks like your correct!! some how it is trying to reach my connection string which is placed in appsetting.json and the connection fails every time. i’d appreciate it if you can list the correct steps to connect the database with my application and any thing i should be aware of.

Comment: You'll need to post a significant amount more information (and not screen shots) for us to be able to help.  How do you connect to your database?  Is your database an AWS RDS or is it local to the beanstalk machine?  How do you configure your connection?